# Python sort a complicated list in list

Tags: python

My list:

```
a = [[["a", 0], ["b", 7], ['c', 3]], 9, [['d', 0], ['e', 5], ['f', 7]], 5, [['g', 8], ['h', 3]], 3, [['i', 0], ['j', 1], ['k', 3]], 3]
```

I want to sort the list by the number after "]]," as the list above like: 9, 5, 3 and 3.
I tried:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

But i got error: TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Well, what is the first element of `3`? That's not going to work, because you have integers in your list as well as lists.

Comment: Ok, i got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is your ints aren’t associated with the list; currently you have `[list, int, list, int, list, int, ...]` instead of `[(list, int), (list, int), (list, int), ...]`. If your list is generated by your code, try rewriting it to output list–int pairs. Otherwise, try regenerating a new list by stepping through your list two at a time

```
iterable = iter(a)
new_list = list(zip(iterable, iterable))
new_list.sort(key=lambda k: k[1])
```

Comment: This works, but I don't know if I like this - it relies on the inner working of "zip", which is an implementation detail.

Comment: No, this is exactly how `zip` is supposed to work. `zip` cycles through each of its arguments and takes `next()` from each one to yield its next item. `list1, list2 = zip( * many_pairs )` works exactly because of this—`zip` takes the first item from each pair in `many_pairs` to form `list1`, then does the same thing for the second item from each pair to form `list2`.

Comment: Ok - the behavior is actually in `zip` s spec- "The left-to-right evaluation order of the iterables is guaranteed. "

Comment: of course it is, otherwise `merged = zip(list1, list2)` wouldn’t work, nor would its inverse.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[["a", 0], ["b", 7], ['c', 3]], 9, [['d', 0], ['e', 5], ['f', 7]], 5, [['g', 8], ['h', 3]], 3, [['i', 0], ['j', 1], ['k', 3]], 3]
```

In this list of yours, the numbers and the inner-lists are independent elements of the main lists. S, there is no sorting possible - it is "apples" and "oranges" - Now, if you want to group each inner list with the following number, and them sort that, it is another history. To group:

```
b = [a[i: i +2] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)]
```

And now:

```
b.sort(key x=lambda x[1])
```